# using sed on a file in the sub-directory

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I have a txt file contains all the file_names in the sub-directories. Something like this:

```
/person/name/abc.xml: somestring
/person/address/ddd.xml: somestring
/person/address/ccc.xml: somestring
```

So my script is to loop this txt file and take the directory (before the colon :), and put it at the end of the sed command.

the sed command worked if I run one in the parent directory, but when I run the script below, the 'my_file' variable doesn't contain the directory string value. It's strange because the 'my_file' variable values shows up from the echo command.

```
while IFS='' read -r LINE || [ -n "${LINE}" ]; do
    my_file=$(${LINE} | grep -oE '^[^:]+')
    echo "$my_file"
    sed -i 's/stringA/stringB/g' ./$my_file
done < directory_list.txt
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve] with intput (which you did), expected output, current output, any errors or logs.  This willl help me understand the "worked if I run one in the parent directory ...".  Try `"./${my_file}"` at the end of your `sed`, just to make sure nothing weird is happening to `$my_file`.

Comment: Another point, you mention you want to process a sub-directory, but if your input file has `/person/name/abc.xml`, this means that there is a `person` directory under your root (`/`).  If the `person` directory is a sub-directory to your current location, it should be expressed as `./person/name/abc.xml` or just `person/name/abc.xml`.

Comment: @Nic3500 , the expected output for the sed command is: `sed -i 's/stringA/stringB/g' ./person/name/abc.xml` and yes, I'm running it in the parent directory of the Person folder. I guess my question should've been 'why the value of the variable $my_file is not passed into the command'

Comment: You should replace: 

my_file=$(${LINE} | grep -oE '^[^:]+') 

with 

my_file=${my_file%%:*}